# Keras Convolution layer kernel size with more than 3 channels

Tags: keras, deep-learning, convolution, autoencoder

I have a question regarding the filter of a convolutional layer in keras. I have image data with 4 channels which are fed through a 3D convolutional network, and Iam not sure how to set up the Conv3D layer in keras.

According to the Keras documentation, the kernel size is given by (depth, width and height).

Now Iam wondering if it would be correct to set up my Conv3D layer like this (i.ex. with 128 filters):

```
Conv3D(128, (4,3,3), activation='relu',padding = 'same')
```

(My input is given according to the channel last convention).

Thanks in advance,

Mike

Comment: I think what you're doing is correct for the first layer.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad!
And thanks for the hint "first layer" as I think I did it wrong in the rest of my network. 
Please correct me if Iam wrong:
A kernel of (4,3,3) is only needed in the first layer as the convolutional operation results in a 2D feature map, right? So for the rest of the network I could use a kernel of (3,3,3)?

Comment: Actually it results in 3d feature maps. The depth of your kernel in the first layer should be 4 because your input has 4 channels. But for example for the second layer your feature map has 128 channels, so you use a kernel of (128, 3, 3).

Comment: Thanks again for the comment. 
That makes sense... Iam still unsure though how to write this in keras. When working with 3 channel images and 3D volumes I normally define the kernel size as (3,3,3) in all layers. Is that wrong?

Comment: Lets say your second convolution layer has 256 filters, the code would be something like this: `Conv3D(256, (128,3,3), activation='relu',padding = 'same')`